# Problema con relaciones en laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relaciones

Estoy con un problema sencillo calculo, pero no le encuentro la vuelta...

Tengo dos tablas: Una es la de `users` y la otra es `churchs`

El tema es que cada `user` pertenece a una `church`. Para eso en la tabla de `users` coloqué un campo que se llama `church_id`. Y a partir de ahí quiero hacer la relación.

En el modelo **User** coloqué el siguiente código:

```
public function church()
    {
        return $this -> belongsTo('App\Church');
    }
```

y en la vista simplemente coloco `{{ $user -> church -> name }}` para que muestre el nombre pero me devuelve un error **Trying to get property 'name' of non-object**

Intenté colocando los campos relacionales: `return $this -> belongsTo('App\Church', 'church_id', 'id');` pero no resultó, me da el mismo error.

Alguien que me pueda dar una mano?

Comment: Una relación uno a uno o uno a varios?

Comment: @BetaM un **user** pertenece a una sola **church**

Comment: Ok, edita y muestranos el modelo `Church` así como la consulta de donde sale `$user`

Comment: Por cierto has un `dd()` a la variable `$users` y agrega el resultado de eso a tu pregunta

Comment: @BetaM gracias! me bastó hacer el dd() para darme cuenta que tenía un registro null para el campo church_id por lo que me estaba dando el error. Solucionado!

Comment: Entonces para que no dejes la pregunta abandonada por favor considera publicar el problema y la solcuión

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resuelto.

Tenía un registro con valor null para `church_id`. Al no tener un valor definido, estaba dando el error que no encontraba el valor para ese campo en la relación.

Para evitar eso, lo mejor es colocar un `if` para comprobar si existe.

Comment: Cuando el sistema lo permita no olvides marcarla como aceptada